# inka3d export loading in three.js

Tags: export, three.js

is it possible to load an with inka3d exported project from maya in three.js?
i tried the export from three.js for maya but that didn't work. When i export with Inka3d and open the created html file the Maya animation runs perfect.

is there a problem with the animation i builded in maya? It is a paper card which is doing a simple folding with four joints.
how is the best way to open and load it with three.js? I want to use three.js for the rest of the coding.

thanks

here is my code i tried to open with three.js maya plugin exported file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
    <body onload="webGLStart();">



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Karte2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, loader;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 1000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    loader.load( "js/Karte2.js", function( geometry ) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
        mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
        mesh.position.y = 150;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
         scene.add( mesh );
    } );



    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    //mesh.rotation.x += 0.05;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

        </script>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a inka3d file format spec somewhere?

Comment: no there isnt one. but here is my .js file i want to load with three.js
 


[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/puhZF/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to load inka3d content with three.js, but it should be possible to use inka3d and three.js simultaneously, i.e. render something with inka3d onto a canvas and then something with three.js ontop of it (or other way around). inka3d only exposes an interface and no file format because it works by code generation. maya's dependency graph is translated into js code. so all you can do after export is controlling the attributes in your scene (e.g. pCube1.translate) that are in the "interface". you can define which attributes are in the interface in the export options when exporting from maya. inka3d's json format also contains code that is stored in string fields which is eval()ed after loading.